# ¿Como remover un carácter de una cadena por posición? Python

Tags: python

La siguiente funcion recibe como parametros una cadena a la cual se le desea remover un caracer (s) y la posicion del caracter (n), por ejemplo para la cadena "casa" en la posicion 1 deberia remover el caracter "a", pero el metodo replace remplaza todos los caracteres "a".

```
string ="casa"
Resultado deseado = "csa"
Resultado obtenido = "cs"
```

Alguien podria ayudarme con algun consejo sobre como solucionar el problema? 
  Adjunto el codigo a continuacion

```py
def remover_caracter(s, n):

    resultado=""
    longitud=len(s)
    i=0

    if n < longitud:
       resultado = s.replace(s[n], "")
    return resultado

print(remover_caracter("casa",1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dijo abulafia usa slices. Dado que sabes el indice el cual quieres remover lo mejor seria dejar tu función de esta forma:

```
def remover_caracter(s, n):
    inicio = 0
    fin = len(s)
    resultado = s[inicio:n] + s[n+1:fin]
    return resultado

print(remover_caracter("casa",1))
```

Comment: Hombre, yo no quise darle el código para ayudarle a pensar, y vas tú y se lo das! XD. Y ya puestos, se podría haber simplificado enormemente pues como explico en mi respuesta el inicio y fin del slice son opcionales, por lo que podrías haber hecho una función con una sola línea:  `return s[:n] + s[n+1:]`

Comment: La verdad es que lo pensé, creo que fueron las ansias de responder, es mi primera semana en esta plataforma quería sentirme util jeje, pero lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima, y si, ahora que lo pienso hubiera sido mucho mas simple la solución que planteas. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) por defecto, reemplaza todas las ocurrencias de una determinada cadena, para indicar que solo buscas hacerlo únicamente con la primer ocurrencia del caracter `a` deberías indicar esto por medio del parámetro `count`, es decir reemplaza esto:

```
resultado = s.replace(s[n], "")
```

por

```
resultado = s.replace(s[n], "", 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Las cadenas son inmutables, es decir, no puedes cambiar ni eliminar ninguno de sus elementos. Lo que puedes hacer es construir *otra* cadena que sea igual a la que recibes como parámetro, excepto que no contenga el carácter n-ésimo.

Hay varias formas de hacer esto, pero ya que se trata de un ejercicio no voy a darte la solución completa, sino sólo las ideas necesarias para que lo intentes.

### Usando *slices*

Un *slice* es una "rodaja" de una cadena, que se especifica con la sintaxis `cadena[inicio:fin]` y devuelve otra cadena con todos los caracteres comprendidos entre sus índices `inicio` y `fin-1`. Si omites `inicio` (así, `cadena[:fin]`) se tomará como inicio el principio de la cadena. Si omites `fin` (así, `cadena[inicio:]`) se tomará como fin el final de la cadena.

Si haces dos *slices* de la cadena de entrada, uno que vaya desde el comienzo hasta el carácter `n-1` y otro que vaya desde el `n+1` hasta el final, y los concatenas (el operador `+` sirve para concatenar cadenas), tendrás lo que buscas.

### Convirtiendo la cadena en lista y de nuevo en cadena

Una lista sí que es *mutable* y se le puede eliminar cualquiera de sus elementos. Puedes convertir una cadena dada en lista haciendo `lista = list(cadena)`.

Una vez lo tienes convertido en lista, eliminar su elemento n-ésimo es simplemente hacer `lista.pop(n)`.

Pero debes retornar una cadena, no una lista, con lo que deberás volver a convertir la lista anterior en la cadena que retornarás. Para convertir listas en cadenas se usa `str.join(lista)`, siendo `str` la cadena que se usará como separador a la hora de concatenar entre sí todos los elementos de la lista. Si no quieres que haya separador, basta hacer `"".join(lista)`

### Usando `replace()`

Este es el enfoque que intentaste. Mira la respuesta de Patricio Moracho para ver por qué no te funcionó. En todo caso es un enfoque "poco natural" para resolver este ejercicio.